# Better way to filter DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I currently have a `DataTable` with the following columns: Date, X1, Y1, Z1, X2, Y2, Z2... Xn, Yn, Zn.

When populated, Date ALWAYS has a value, and X/Y/Z1 to X/Y/Zn can be `DBNull`, a `string`, or an `int`. If the entire row with the exception of Date, is DBNull, i would like to remove that particular row.

I am currently doing an exhaustive search, looping through each row with a for loop, and then with a nested for loop, checking each cell, if i do not find any data (ie. only dbnull's), i then call RemoveAt, and reset the outer loop to start at zero again.

Is there a better/less hacky way of performing this operation? The initial building of the datatable cannot be modified, this must be something that happens post building.

Comment: Can they also be `Nullable<int>` or what if the `string` is `null` (instead of `DBNull.Value`)?

Comment: you doesn't need to start at zero you just need to search at the same Rowindex after RemoveAt because it ride up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove a row if all columns has `DbNull.Value`.
Try the following to do that.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
string[] columns = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                                .Skip(1)//skip to ignore first column
                                .ToArray();
```

**Method1:**
Remove all invalid rows

```
var invalidRows = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => columns.All(c => x.Field<object>(c) == DBNull.Value))
    .ToArray();

foreach (var row in invalidRows)
{
    table.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

**Method2:** take only valid rows and make new `DataTable` as suggested my @Tim in comments to improve performance when you have many invalid rows

```
var newTable = table.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(x => columns.Any(c => x.Field<object>(c) != DBNull.Value))
             .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: I want to remove rows where all columns except the first column, has the value of dbnull.value.

Comment: @bizzehdee Updated my answer, `Skip(1)` to ignore first column

Comment: Instead of taking all rows that are invalid, create an array from them and a loop which removes them from the table, wouldn't it be better(in terms of readability and efficiency) to [take only rows that are valid and use `CopyToDataTable` directly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19004092/284240)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Point taken and updated my answer. If only few rows are invalid it is worth doing a delete rather than creating a new table. So provided both ways :)

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you. Try this

```
    var ordered = yourdatatable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("ColumnName") != null);

if (ordered.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            yourdatatable= orderedCopyToDataTable();
                        }
```

you can do the same for other columns as well.

Or

Why don't you check for the null values in your query. check for `ISNULL(columnName, value)` As ColumnName. Check more details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

Comment: DateTime cannot be null :)

Answer (score 0):

ATTENTION : THESE ARE MY EXAMPLES>>NOT EXCATLLY FOR YOUR TABLE>>>SO CHANGE IT FOR YOURSELF
The Main Help is Here >> [Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk13kdh0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

And Then 
 Way one :

```
dtData.Select("ID=1 AND ID2=3");
```

Way two :

```
GridFieldDAO dao = new GridFieldDAO();
    //Load My DataTable
    DataTable dt = dao.getDT();
    //Get My rows based off selection criteria
    DataRow[] drs = dt.Select("(detailID = 1) AND (detailTypeID = 2)");
    //make a new "results" datatable via clone to keep structure
    DataTable dt2 = dt.Clone();
    //Import the Rows
    foreach (DataRow d in drs)
    {
        dt2.ImportRow(d);
    }
    //Bind to my new DataTable and it will only show rows based off selection 
    //criteria
    myGrid.DataSource = dt2;
    myGrid.DataBind();
```

And The best Way is :

```
DataTable tblFiltered = table.AsEnumerable()
      .Where(row => row.Field<String>("Nachname") == username
               &&   row.Field<String>("Ort") == location)
      .OrderByDescending(row => row.Field<String>("Nachname"))
      .CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this little Linq query:

```
var columnsWithoutDate = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Skip(1);
table = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => columnsWithoutDate.Any(col => !row.IsNull(col)))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

`Skip(1)` returns all columns but the first, so your date column is excluded. The `Where` enumerates all `DataRows` in the table and takes all rows with at least one non-null field(see:[`DataRow.IsNull(column)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ak67st4.aspx)). Finally `CopyToDataTable` creates a new `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

modified answer:

```
myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(a => a.ItemArray.Count(b=>b != DBNull.Value)==1).ToList().ForEach(row => dataTable.Rows.Remove(row));
```

I checked, it works.

**EDIT**:

in response to @Tim Schmelter comment:

> 1 . you need myDataTable.AsEnumerable() in C#

If you have a strongly typed DataTable, you do not. I assumed it's the case, since OP says:

> The initial building of the datatable cannot be modified, this must be
>   something that happens post building.

Maybe I did't understand what he meant (my English sometimes fails me)

> 2 . count the non-null fields is incorrect since a string can be null
>   which is not the same as if it is DBNull.Value(also according OP's
>   specifications)

You are probably right. If OP says he only wants DBNull, the second condition should be removed (it's a bad habit of mine to check for null just in case)

> 3 . ToList creates another List which is redundant

Yes. And if there's no ToList(), ForEach() can't be used. The old fashioned foreach can be used instead, or beter for loop (since foreach doesn't like when you try to modify collection inside it). Still you have to keep your result in some way.

> 4 . DataRow.Delete does it not remove from the table what is desired,
>   but it flags it as deleted for a DataAdapter(OP's has not mentioned
>   that he's using one, it is also not desired).

Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: This has several problems: 1. you need `myDataTable.AsEnumerable()` in C# 2. count the non-null fields is incorrect since a string can be null which is not the same as if it is `DBNull.Value`(also according OP's specifications) 3. `ToList` creates another `List` which is redundant 4. `DataRow.Delete` does it not remove from the table what is desired, but it flags it as deleted for a `DataAdapter`(OP's has not mentioned that he's using one, it is also not desired).

Comment: I have removed my downvote for the efforts. However, the points of criticism remain. The `DataTable` could also be one that is not under OP's control because he (his method/class/dll) is just the consumer, so there is nothing indicating a strongly typed `DataTable`.  Using `Count` instead of `Any` (or `All`) ist bad for another reason: it needs to check all items of a sequence(what could be a large, time consuming query) to get the count even if you just want to know that there is one. `ToList` + `ForEach` is a bad habit i often see. You can also use a cheap `foreach` to call `Delete`.

Comment: Neither `Delete` nor `AcceptChanges` remove the rows as from the table. `Delete` does something completely different and has an effect only together with a `DataAdapter` to delete the record from the database. OP wants to remove the invalid rows from the (in-memory) table. Therefore you can create a new table or use `DataTable.Rows.Remove/RemoveAt`.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter you are totally right with the AcceptChanges part. I've just confirmed it. And all this time I was convinced it actually works how MSDN says it does (quote: "Deleted rows are removed."). ToList() is necessary so it doesn't complain about modifying the underlying collection in ForEach. Normal foreach can be used, I just like this one (only 1 line of code). Is it really that much cheaper? I don't know how to use Any() or All() in this situation, since OP says the first column always will have value.

Comment: You are right, if you want to call `Delete` you have to use something other than `foreach`(you can change the rows without problem, but you cannot change their `RowState`). That's why i prefer `CopyToDataTable` on the "positive" rows instead of deleting "negatives". For an example of `Any` have a look at [my approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19004092/284240).

Comment: @Tim Schmelter your use of Skip() is really neat. Although CopyToDataTable has its own set of setbacks. It creates a copy of all your data, not simply references them so when your table is big, the Garbage collector has a feast. It usually takes more time (I once had a solution when it took 10x more time than the pure linq approach). Also, when you're using strong typed datatables, casting the result to something usefull proves difficult (and time consuming).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using RowFilter of DataTable?

```
DataTable dt = GetData();
//set the filter
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "----your filter----";
//then access the DataView
foreach (DataRowView drv in dt.DefaultView)
{
            //you can also get a row from rowview
            DataRow dr = drv.Row;
}
```

Check this documentation, they also explain how to handle null values in filters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx

You can also use Select() method with same filter, refer the below answer there is a good comparison on both approach.

[DataView.RowFilter Vs DataTable.Select() vs DataTable.Rows.Find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832304/dataview-rowfilter-vs-datatable-select-vs-datatable-rows-find)

I would not suggest using **AsEnumerable()** approach, though looks like simple code but it is just like doing a foreach loop on rows and having IF conditions.

DataTable filter approach should be faster than **AsEnumerable()** (I am not sure, but I am assuming this because DataTable is .net's powerful data structure to handle tabular data)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like this:

```
        var test = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                   where (!row.IsNull("col1") || !row.IsNull("col2"))
                   select row;

        //option1
        DataTable dt = test.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();

        //option2
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(String));
        dt2.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(Int32));

        foreach (var v in test)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt2.NewRow();
            dr["col1"] = v.Field<String>("col1");
            dr["col1"] = v.Field<Int32>("col2");
            dt2.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

Comment: columns are dynamic, so i cant list each column in code statically. Hence the X/Y/Z1 to X/Y/Zn