# filtering large DataTable in for loop

Tags: c#, performance, filter, datatable

I have a DataTable with Row.Count=2.000.000 and two columns containing integer values.

So what i need is filtering the datatable in a loop, efficiently.

I'm doing it with;

```
for (int i= 0; i< HugeDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  tempIp= int.Parse(HugeDataTable.Rows[i]["col1"].ToString());

  var filteredUsers = tumu.Select("col1= " + tempIp.ToString()).Select(dr => dr.Field<int>("col2")).ToList(); 

HashSet<int> filtered = new HashSet<int>(filteredUsersByJob2);

  Boolean[] userVector2 = userVectorBase
      .Select(item => filtered.Contains(item))
      .ToArray();

  ...
}
```

What should I do to improve performance. I need every little trick. Datatable index, linq search are what i came up with google search. I d like hear your suggestions. 
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have 2m rows in a `DataTable`? Why not filter it on the database side first?

Comment: How says @Lloyd "Why not filter it on the database side first?". But anyway, you can use `AsParallel()` and if you have 2 or more cores, it will increase the speed of your query. 
Usage: `filteredUsers = tumu.AsParallel().Select("col1= " + tempIp.ToString()).Select(dr => dr.Field<int>("col2")).ToList(); `

Comment: Some mehods are described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832304/dataview-rowfilter-vs-datatable-select-vs-datatable-rows-find

Answer (score 1):

You may use Parallel.For

```
Parallel.For(0, table.Rows.Count, rowIndex => {
var row = table.Rows[rowIndex];
// put your per-row calculation here});
```

[Please have a look at this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/61ee4ac4-4d2c-4b9a-ba5a-58d044789bfb/how-to-do-a-loop-over-a-datatable-faster-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

Answer (score 0):

You're using a double for loop. If your tumu contains a lot of rows it will be very slow.

Fix: make a dictionary with all users before your for loop. In your for loop check the dictionary.

Something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, id> usersByCode;//Init + fill it in
for (int i= 0; i< HugeDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  tempIp= int.Parse(HugeDataTable.Rows[i]["col1"].ToString());
  if(usersByCode.Contains(tempId) 
  {
    //Do something
  }
}
```

Comment: i forgot to mention but my col1 and col2 isnt unique

Comment: You can also use a Dictionary<string, List<id>> if there are multiple records per key.