# c# DataGridView bound to datatable not updating after .select() on datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, datagridview, bindingsource

I am learning to use the advanced DataGridView and am having trouble updating the DataGridView after a `.Select()` on a datatable. I've found a lot of SO posts on `.RowFilter` and have gotten that to work but I havent had luck with the `.Select()`.

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832304/dataview-rowfilter-vs-datatable-select-vs-datatable-rows-find) stating that `.Select()` is better for larger tables, thus the reason for trying to use `.Select()`

I am under the impression that if a datatable is bound to a binding source, then it should update the DataGridView automatically, but that seems to be not the case.

When i step through, I can see at my line of:

`DataRow[] test = dataTable.Select("foundTerm = 'cat' OR foundTerm = 'dog'");`

The `test` object now has the correct amount of rows in it which is great however, I just seem to be missing the last step of how to update the DataGridView and I haven't found the answer in my searches.

So far, I have the following:

```
private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataTable = new DataTable();

        bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;

        // COLUMNS ADDED TO DATATABLE

        // DATA ROWS ADDED TO DATATABLE

    }
    advancedDataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;

}


private void advancedDataGridView1_FilterStringChanged(object sender, Zuby.ADGV.AdvancedDataGridView.FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow[] test = dataTable.Select("foundTerm = 'cat' OR foundTerm = 'dog'");


        advancedDataGridView1.Refresh();
        advancedDataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
        bindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
        advancedDataGridView1.Update();
        dataTable.AcceptChanges();

    }
```

Any and all help/direction is appreciated.

Comment: I am not understanding the posted code. Where is the line of code… `advancedDataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;` executed? From this, we can conclude that resetting the `BindingSource` will accomplish nothing since the grid’s data source is the `dataTable` and not the `bindingSource`. In addition, if you use the `bindingSource`, you would want to filter it as opposed to the `dataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

You attempts won't work; select returns you a collection of DataRow but does absolutely nothing to change what the the datagridview is showing as it's data

Perhaps a different example will help

```
textBox1.Text = "Hello world";

var s = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 5);
```

What do you expect s to contain? What do you expect the textbox to show?

Answers:

```
s is "Hello"
Textbox shows "Hello world"
```

---

Select gives you a collection of rows matching some criteria, but the datagridview will carry on showing the whole data table contents for the same reason. BindingSource has nothing to do with this, and is just passing data through

I'd recommend you just have this set up so "datagridview is bound to bindingsource is bound to datatable" and use the RowFilter of the binding source. From a user perspective, you shouldn't be presenting a user with a dataset so massive that any of the suggested methods in that ancient SO post (that links to an MSDN article that is also garbage, btw) are any different

No one in their right mind would load a million rows into a datatable and then find the fastest way to have c# find the one (or ten) rows the user is interested in; they would write an SQL SELECT query that leaves 999,990 of the rows in the database and transfer the 10 wanted rows; the network time of moving nearly a million unwanted rows *massively exceeds* the time taken to look through them on the client side